# How to fix being limited to 1 client reading from Azure ServiceBus

Tags: c#, azure, queue, azure-web-app-service, servicebus

I have something that's been quite the head scratcher for me...

I have a small service that reads messages from an Azure ServiceBus queue and stores the data in a CosmosDB collection.

The problem is that I can't get my service to scale. I have been able to optimize things to improve the number of messages read per second for one instance of the service. However, adding more instances of the service slightly *degrades* the number of messages read per second in total!

It's important to note that sending messages to the queue in batches works like a charm, I can send 1000-2000 messages per second to the queue without any issues. *Reading* from the queue is the issue.

My handler is slightly CPU intensive, and the messages range from approximately 2 KB to 900 KB in size, the average being somewhere around 25 KB. I've gotten one instance to handle approximately 41.5 messages per second now.

If I add a second instance of the service (which is an Azure Web App by the way) the total number of messages read per second for all instances drops to approximately 40. Adding yet another instance decreases it to closer to 38.

The actual code that reads messages from the queue (and handles retries, deadlettering etc.) is part of an internal company framework, which a lot of other services use, none of which have this issue. Other services have the expected behavior that performance scales linearly with the number of service instances (up to the max that ServiceBus can handle, obviously).

I have the same problem on two different Azure subscriptions (TEST and PROD) which both use the Premium ServiceBus tier.

I am not using sessions on the queue.

**Has anyone here ever had a similar issue, and how did you solve it?**

Things I've tried:

- Switching out only the code that has to do with getting things off of
  ServiceBus with code reading from blob storage instead. This gave me
  orders of magnitude better throughput to CosmosDB (approximately
  15,000 documents written pr. second vs. 41.6 when the source was
  ServiceBus). I got such high throughput by scaling out, which is what I'm having issues with when using ServiceBus So CosmosDb is definitely not the bottleneck.
- I have tried deleting and recreating the queue as well as tweaking various things in my code - but logically, it seems to me, that whatever I do in my code should only be able to impact the performance of a single instance of the service.
- I have tried running the service locally on my computer while it was also running in Azure. From Splunk logs I could then see that during a representative minute the Azure instance of the service handled 1371 messages, while the local instance of the service only handled 23 messages. So, as I've been saying, there seems to be some kind of deadlock or something going on here. Further analysis shows that the instance in Azure spent an average of 247 milliseconds processing a message, while the local instance spent an average of 66 *seconds*! If a lock expires or an unhandled exception otherwise occurs, a message is put back on the queue, and deadlettered after 10 failed delivery attempts. So it seems maybe most of the messages processed locally failed and were put back on the queue and then processed by the Azure instance eventually (this is my guess).

The only shared resources between instances of my web app are ServiceBus and CosmosDb, and as noted above, I've ruled out CosmosDb. However, seeing as I'm having the same issue in both our TEST and PROD subscriptions (our DEV subscription doesn't allow scaling out), and I've tried recreating the queue a few times in various different ways, it can't be the queue itself either, and none of the other queues in use on the same ServiceBus instance are having this issue.

Tweaking/Optimizing code has, as expected, only had impact on the performance of one instance. The possible, as far as I can tell, external bottlenecks have been ruled out. The one remaining thing, our internal framework which handles the actual reading of the messages from the queue, has also been ruled out by the fact that the exact same version of the framework is used in many other web apps where scaling out has been demonstrated to work.

I feel pretty check-mated out here...

SOLUTION: Forgot to update this question, so at last here it is... We eventually managed to set aside time to focus completely on this problem, and through various testing we concluded that it was a combination of using the ReadBatchAsync method in the SDK and having rather large messages that was the cause of this issue. Switching to using OnMessageAsync fixed it.

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is the ServiceBus and not CosmoDB?

Comment: Pretty sure - as I have tried various work-arounds using blob storage instead of ServiceBus, and otherwise the same code for storing in CosmosDb, and then I've gotten _much_ higher throughput to CosmosDb (orders of magnitude better - but at the cost of a _lot_ more complexity and other issues).

Comment: Just to clarify: when using blob storage I did see significant increase in throughput to CosmosDb every time I added a new instance of the service.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure web apps but can you run one locally and then scale out so that you can observe the impact on memory/CPU etc.? Or can you monitor this in Azure? If scaling out to two or more services behaves as you describe it suggests to me that there is resource contention between them.

Comment: By the way, my initial comment related to an experience I have had where the database was definitely the bottleneck. Scaling out apps which simply read and wrote to Azure ServiceBus Topics definitely increased scalabilty but I was running them on a local machine.

Comment: I can monitor CPU/memory in Azure. The graphs show total CPU and memory % used for all instances, as well as I/O. Adding an instance halves the CPU usage, while memory usage only goes slightly down. Data output halves every time I add an instance (say, from 3 MB/s to 1.5MB/s). It _seems_ like messages on the queue are locked (in fact, they are) and the new instance is unable to read the next set of still unlocked messages, or something, which is extremely weird.

Comment: Are you reading messages in batches?

Comment: Yes, it seems our internal framework does that. It uses QueueClient's ReceiveBatchAsync method. It would be strange if that could cause this issue, as all our other services use the same framework.

Comment: Going from a 1-core instance to a 2-core instance also had zero impact on performance.

Comment: Have you tried scaling out by making your app multi-threaded and using the same MessageFactory to create each queue client? It's just occurred to me that I did that rather than running multiple app instances.

Comment: That's already the case I think (my app is multi-threaded as all methods are async Tasks). However, I have no control over how many QueueClient instances are created (though I think it might only be one per app instance), as that is handled under the hood in our internal framework - and as stated, this framework is used by all other services, which don't have this issue. In any case, from what I've read, one would need several MessageFactory instances to increase throughput from one app if the connection is the bottleneck (don't think it is in this case).

Answer (score 1):

It is usually not a good idea to have `async void` operations.

Additionally, you could also refactor the processing to be invoked in batches as well.

First approach assumes an inability to make `StartProcessMessage` async

```
void StartProcessMessage(Message m) {
    //...
}

public async Task Start() {
    while (true) {
        var messages = (await _queueClient.ReceiveBatchAsync(Math.Max(1, _configuration.MaxConcurrentCalls - _messagesInProgress))).ToArray();
        Interlocked.Add(ref _messagesInProgress, messages.Length);
        var tasks = messages.Select(m => Task.Run(() => StartProcessMessage(m)));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks); //process in parallel.
        while (_messagesInProgress > _configuration.MaxConcurrentCalls) {
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

The second approach assumes that `StartProcessMessage` can be refactored to be async

```
Task StartProcessMessage(Message m) {
    //...
}

public async Task Start() {
    while (true) {
        var messages = (await _queueClient.ReceiveBatchAsync(Math.Max(1, _configuration.MaxConcurrentCalls - _messagesInProgress))).ToArray();
        Interlocked.Add(ref _messagesInProgress, messages.Length);
        var tasks = messages.Select(m => StartProcessMessage(m));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks); //process in parallel.
        while (_messagesInProgress > _configuration.MaxConcurrentCalls) {
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be able to try this, although, as I've pointed out in my OP, my issue can logically not be caused by anything in that part of the code, as that exact code is used in many other services (it's from an internal framework we've built) who do not have my issue. That code example was just to give an idea about what is happening when receiving messages. I think I probably need to add more code to clarify things... Will do so soon.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to first eliminate the possibility that it is the handling code that is the problem. Try running with a dummy `StartProcessMessage` that does nothing to ensure that it is not the problem/bottleneck i.e. too many writers write to some shared resource or something similar.

Another option you can try is using the latest .Net library `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`. The classes that are available there allows for running a built in loop that allows `MaxConcurrentCalls` in a more natural way and easy way. But ensuring it's not the handler is the first thing you should try. If you already did maybe you should share it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am already using the lates SDK NuGets from MS. I'm not a veteran C#/Azure developer, so maybe I missed something, but how can I have a shared resource between _separate instances_ of the web app? My problem isn't with parallelism within one instance, but between separate instances of the web app.

Comment: I don't know the details of what you do in message handlers, but an access to a common database can be an example of such a shared resource that limits maximum connections or does some other type of throttling. You wrote about CosmoDb, is it possible that it does some limiting/throttling when it encounters too many calls e.g.? If you are not sure, so it's always worth to verify without any actual handling, then you will know for sure if it's the service bus or something else. But my random guess: it's too many simultaneous calls.

Comment: You can read a bit about throughput of CosmoDB here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units. It seems it's definitely does some throttling based on the tier.

Comment: Thanks, but I am well aquainted with the concept of RUs. And as stated in comments elsewhere  here (I'll try and add more info to the question based on what has been discussed in comments), I have tried using blob storage instead of ServiceBus, while keeping everything else the same, and then I got orders of magnitude higher throughput to CosmosDB, so it can't be anything to do with the database. At the most, using blob storage, I got a throughput of 15,000 documents per second, while with ServiceBus I get a maximum of 41.6 per second.

Comment: Web apps run in Azure App Service if I am not mistaken and the resources there are limited perhaps? Did you try to run your clients on actual hardware or some place to rule out the possibility of shared resources for running Web apps?

Comment: I have now tried running the service locally on my machine while it was also running in Azure, and I got the same total amount of messages handled as when only running the service in Azure. The debug window in visual Studio didn't provide any relevant info either, I think. It wrote a LOT of messages like: _"DocDBTrace Information: 0 : 2018-07-17T11:32:14.6544181Z, CorrelatedActivityId: [GUID], ActivityId [GUID] | DocumentProducer Id: 60, MoveNext Metrics: [Turnaround Time: 1071.2901ms, Response Time: 1071.2767ms, Run Time: 0.0042ms, Wait Time: 1071.2862ms, Number Of Preemptions: 1]"._

Comment: I must say sorry then, I am out of ideas why does it happen. One thing I can suggest if you want to dig deeper into what's going no in the client is the built in diagnostics. It's very verbose and not easy to navigate, but maybe will offer some help. You can find more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing.  It's a bit non-trivial to connect to it, but not super hard. It's questionable though if you'll get much help from it

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks. I just noticed in the Splunk logs, that when I ran my service both locally and in Azure, a representative minute-interval showed 1371 messages handled by the Azure service and 23 by the local service...